# JEditorPane, or any java text area fill the JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe, layout-manager, jtextcomponent

I'm writing a simple text editor in java, I have done it before now I have some new ideas, normally when I put in a JTextArea when I have a FlowLayout on my JFrame it will fill what is left of the JFrame.  However this time it's not.  Could someone help me out trying to get it to fill the rest of my JFrame?  Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code that you have so we can help you.

Comment: See also the [Nested layout example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) which demonstrates how to combine layouts for different layouts in different parts of the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html 
Java does have various layouts. For making dynamic body changes you have to learn more flexible layouts like grid or grid bag layout. Hope this help.